# How to prove the existence of a continuous function from [0, 1] to an open, connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, connectedness

I was recently asked to prove that for an open, connected subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that, for any $x, y \in G$, there always exists a continuous function $f: [0, 1] \to G$ such that $f(0) = x, f(1) = y$.

This sounds like a rephrasing of "prove that open, connected sets are path-connected." But, how do I prove the statement above without talking about "paths"?

I'm not sure how to approach proving the existence of a such a function. Should I construct one? Show by contradiction that there can't not be one?

My approach has involved trying to construct a function that traverses finitely many open balls in $G$ whose union is connected and contains both $x$ and $y$. But I don't know how to build this finite collection, or prove that it exists.

Because $G$ is open, there exists an open ball centered at $x$ of some radius $\epsilon_x > 0$. So $x \in B(x, \epsilon_x) \subset G$. For any $z \in B(x, \epsilon_x)$, we can define a function $g: [0, 1] \to B(x, \epsilon_x)$ where $g(a) := az + (1 - a)x$. So, $g(0) = x$ and $g(1) = z$.

And from here, I think I can prove that there exists finitely many balls connecting any $x, y$ in $G$, and define a piecewise linear function that traverses each ball, such that the function is continuous.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: It's easy to find a finite chain of open convex balls from $x$ to $y$ by connectedness and then we glue finitely many line segments to such a function.

Comment: Your functions $f$ are paths. This, the question is exactly the same as the one about path-connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider the set $$A = \{ z \in G : \text{there exists a path from } x \text{ to } z \text{ inside } G \}$$ and show that both $A$ and $G \setminus A$ are open, which means that $A = G$ and so $y \in A$.